# nested attributes without activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, nested-attributes

I am trying to create an invoicing system that does not persist to a database, but passes through to a third party system. Hence, my models are not ActiveRecord as there is no table to persist to. How can I accept nested attributes for invoice line items in my invoice model?

This is an example of the resulting params from my form

```
{"payportal_invoice"=>{"invoice_lines"=>{"quantity"=>["1", "2"], "units"=>["hours", "hours"], "price"=>["10", "20"], "description"=>["desc", "d"]}, "dueDate"=>"10/10/2013", "invoiceNumber"=>"3.13.13.11:47", "description"=>"notes"}, "attachment_name"=>""}
```

I can easily create the invoice model from this params set, but am not sure how to create the line items

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a tableless gem, such as https://github.com/softace/activerecord-tableless?

I've used them for similar situations in the past - you can do all of the standard validations, etc, but without needing to invoke ActiveRecord.